# Split pgn files by players

Tags: pgn

Is there a way to split large PGN files into folders grouped by the players?
For example, in a tournament, each player has several games in one file.
I aim to group each game by players to the respective folders (one game, one file).
So it will produce two files for each match, one for player 1 and one for player 2 in two separate folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you may be able to do it in a DB manager (ChessBase...) or you'll need a bit of coding in [Chess Query Language](http://www.gadycosteff.com/cql/)

---

Download and extract [`cqli`](https://cql64.com/) (a modern rewrite of the original `cql` software) to the folder containing your pgn database

Create a `p1.cql` file, with the following content (this is an example for getting all Kasparov's games) :

```
cql(input database.pgn)

"Kasparov" in player
```

---

Open Powershell/Terminal (depending on your platform), `cd` to the database directory and run

Unix/Linux

```
./cqli --threads 8 p1.cql
```

macOS

```
# For Intel Macs
./cqli-x86_64 --threads 8 p1.cql
# For Apple Silicon Macs
./cqli-arm64 --threads 8 p1.cql
```

Windows

```
./cqli.exe --threads 8 p1.cql
```

---

And you'll find the resulting database in `p1-out.pgn`.

Note that it is a database, to extract it, we can use [kentdjb](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/12951/kentdjb) [`pgn-extract`](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/)

Unzip the windows executable in the database program as previously, or build it from source if you are on Linux/macOS

And then run :

```
./pgn-extract -\#1 p1-out.pgn
```

*The backslash before the `#` is essential*

This will split your pgn into files named `1.pgn`, `2.pgn`...